# Generate random string with specific pattern

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to generate a wordlist using `random` module. The pattern I want is like this:

`D7FE-PWO3-ODKE`

I can generate the strings but I'm not able to figure out how can I get that hyphen `(-)` between them.

```py
import random
import string

wordlist = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits

def random_string(len):

    for i in range(10):
        result = ''.join(random.choice(wordlist) for _ in range(len))
        print(result)

random_string(12)
```

I have tried this approach but this gives whitespaces after each `(-)`.

```py
def random_string():
    
    for i in range(10):
        str1 = ''.join(random.choice(wordlist) for _ in range(4)) + '-'.strip()
        str2 = ''.join(random.choice(wordlist) for _ in range(4)) + '-'.strip()
        str3 = ''.join(random.choice(wordlist) for _ in range(4))
        print(str1, str2, str3)

random_string()
```

Comment: Why do you use `.strip()` ?

Comment: if you just want to print it `print(str1, str2, str3, sep='')` should work

Comment: The function `print` inserts spaces between it's arguments. Use `str1 + str2 + str3`

Comment: Hint: when you wrote `str1 = ''.join(random.choice(wordlist) for _ in range(4)) + '-'.strip()`, why did you *not* instead write `print(''.join(random.choice(wordlist) for _ in range(4)), '-')`? Clearly you know how to *create a string* that doesn't have spaces in it, so if you want to make a longer string that doesn't have any spaces, using those pieces... just do the same thing again? What exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this more flexible and simplier solution which adds only one line of code and still keep readability.

After generation of string, you simply cut the string by every 4 chars and glue them with hyphens.

```python
import random
import string


wordlist = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits


def random_string(str_len, count=10):
    for i in range(count):
        result = ''.join(random.choice(wordlist) for _ in range(str_len))
        # Next line adds the hyphens every 4 characters.
        result = '-'.join(result[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, len(result), 4))
        print(result)


random_string(12)
```

You can also provide another parameters e.g. `group=4` etc. to create even more flexible function. :)

Edit:
This is not list comprehension version of the hyphen concatenation *for cycle*:

```
results = []
for i in range(0, len(result), 4):
    results.append(result[i:i + 4])
print('-'.join(results))
```

Comment: How can we write this in simple for loop?....The last `result` where you used slicing.

Comment: Edit: I added the classic version to the answer. @Mujtaba

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [f-string-formatting](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

```
def random_string():
    for i in range(10):
        str1 = ''.join(random.choice(wordlist) for _ in range(4))
        str2 = ''.join(random.choice(wordlist) for _ in range(4))
        str3 = ''.join(random.choice(wordlist) for _ in range(4))
        
        final = f'{str1}-{str2}-{str3}'
        print(final)
```